# kongregate not defined error javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kongregate

I have included the required files in the head as it says in the docs

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn1.kongregate.com/javascripts/kongregate_api.js'></script>
```

And then right above my scripts i included the script that supposed to define the variable

```
<script>
    kongregateAPI.loadAPI(function(){
        window.kongregate = kongregateAPI.getAPI();
    });
</script>
```

But in the console I am still getting this error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: kongregate is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> And then right above my scripts i included

Does it mean that your code looks like this?

```
<script>
    kongregateAPI.loadAPI(function(){
        window.kongregate = kongregateAPI.getAPI();
    });
</script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn1.kongregate.com/javascripts/kongregate_api.js'></script>
```

If so, you should call kongregateAPI functions after you loaded api js file:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn1.kongregate.com/javascripts/kongregate_api.js'></script>
<script>
    kongregateAPI.loadAPI(function(){
        window.kongregate = kongregateAPI.getAPI();
    });
</script>
```

I've tried it, everything works fine.

Comment: i have <script src="game.js"></script>

Comment: and its abve that but this was a long time ago i was just looking for upvotes :)